# ColdFusion PayPal serverside form post

Tags: forms, post, coldfusion, paypal, cfhttp

I want to submit items to a shopping cart and redirect through to PayPal for payment from the code end of a site using dynamically supplied fields. I have tried using cfhttp but it isn't redirecting through. I tried `resolveurl=yes` and `redirect=yes` but they didn't work either. Is there another way to do this?

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="_cart"             name="cmd">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="1"                 name="upload">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="NZD"               name="currency_code">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="myEmail@gmail.com" name="business">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="My First Item"     name="item_name_1">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="1.00"              name="amount_1">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="1"                 name="quantity_1">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="My Second Item"    name="item_name_2">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="2.00"              name="amount_2">
  <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" value="2"                 name="quantity_2">
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Name-Value Pair API you should be posting to: https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
- according to [docs](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/overview.html).

Btw - [here's](http://tutorial23.easycfm.com/) some tutorial that should be working. Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't look like the NVP API, it seems he is trying to simulate a user click on a PayPal generated button.

Comment: your link to the tutorial doesn't work. And I was trying to simulate a user click